# VueJS, can we watch multiple variables or is there an easier way for data validation?

Tags: vue.js, validation, input, replace, watch

Working in VueJS with a form. I do not POST the form as I would like to keep the information client side for privacy/data sensitivity reasons. So no PHP validation.

I strip the input from possible code as follows but it should be possible to do it shorter. I am a beginner so please ELI5. For example if you use a function, where in the VUE section does it go?

Is it also possible to change a variable to contain the string "* invalid character entered" triggering when the replace function triggers?

Come to think of it, is form input still a vulnerability if it stays client side?

```
 new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            clienTyp: 'B.V.',
            companyName: '',
            noSigCompany: 1,
            n: 0,
            companyAddress: '',
            companyNumber: '',
            companyShortName: '',
            personAddress: '',
            personName: '',
            personShortName: '',
            personPOB: '',
            personDOB: '',
        },
        watch: {
            companyName(val) {
                this.companyName = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            companyAddress(val) {
                this.companyAddress = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            companyNumber(val) {
                this.companyNumber = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            companyShortName(val) {
                this.companyShortName = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            personAddress(val) {
                this.personAddress = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            personName(val) {
                this.personName = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            personShortName(val) {
                this.personShortName = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            personPOB(val) {
                this.personPOB = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
            personDOB(val) {
                this.personDOB = val.replace(/[<>"'`$]/g, "");
            },
```

Comment: As long you make sure the input are escaped it doesn't really matter which characters they enter. But make sure you also do you validations server side, you could always work around an interface.

Also it maybe worth to look at https://vuelidate.js.org/ for valdations

Comment: You can use the vee-validate plugin for front-end validations. I find it very helpful for the form validations.